# document.body.style.backgroundImage does not works

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem with `document.body.style.backgroundImage` tag.
It is woking perfectly on local but not on the server.

```
<a href="roztoky.php" onclick = "document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/roztoky.png)';">
```

On local, backgound is switched with no problem, but on the server the backgroud cames up just for a few seconds and then its overwrited back to defalut

But if I call it like that:

```
<a href="_section/roztoky.php" onclick = "document.getElementById('frame').style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/roztoky.png)';" target="a">
```

It works ...

Any ideas?

Comment: your path to the image is different in each. I would assume that's part of the problem.

Comment: What is up with you guys why are you using inline scripting this is very bad

Comment: We cannot see your online page *or* your local page, so how do you expect us to solve the problem? It’s most probably an issue with the location of files, which is not disclosed at all in the question.

Comment: Did you check the URLs in your code?

Comment: Path is different because once is called from iframe and once from page already loaded into iframe

Comment: And as I said it is woking on the local - and structure is the same, its just copied to server. Background even cames up for a while but then its changed back to default - just on the server not on local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/a668wbsa/2/)

Change

```
<a id="a" href="roztoky.php" onclick = "document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/roztoky.png)';">
```

top

```
$('#a').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(/img/roztoky.png)');
});
```

and

```
<a id="b" href="_section/roztoky.php" onclick = "document.getElementById('frame').style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/roztoky.png)';" target="a">
```

to

```
$('#b').on('click', function() {
    $('#frame').css('background-image', 'url(img/roztoky.png)');
});
```

or with pure javascript

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a668wbsa/1/)

```
    var button_a = document.querySelector("#a"),
    button_b = document.querySelector("#b"),
    myframe  = document.querySelector("#frame");
button_a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    document.body.style["background-image"] = "url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5530/11442019345_d50b753156.jpg)";
},false);
button_b.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    myframe.style.style["background-image"] = "url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3702/11442187163_fdd370b657_n.jpg)";
},false);
```

HTML::

```
<a id="a">body background image</a>
<a id="b">change frame background</a>
<div id="frame"></div>
```

CSS::

```
#frame{
    width:100%;
    height:320px;
}

a{
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background:#ccc;
    border-radius:6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Will try ASAP and let you know.  Thanks so far